# models with uninterpreted sorts

Tags: z3

When Z3 returns a model with an uninterpreted sort, say `Q`, it uses constants of the form `Q!val!0`.

However, if I create a query from scratch and refer to this symbol as an inhabitant of `Q`, then Z3 rightfully complains that `Q!val!0` is an unknown constant.

Essentially, I'm trying to get Z3 to enumerate all the inhabitants of `Q`, by asking it to give me a model that's not the same as the previously returned one. Hence, in subsequent calls to Z3, I need to refer to these constants.

Is there a way to do this using the SMT-Lib2 interface?